# A map of double and 2d double array inside a matrix element

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, probability, markov-chains

I am trying to create a nested matrix in c++ as shown in the picture below;
[Transition Probability Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayCJW.png)

Can anyone please guide me on how to implement that using C++? Here in this matrix, each element contains a probability value and a matrix.

The operations to be performed on these will be insertion and updation. Every time a node visits any of these 4 locations, it will update its probability value and check the time period at that location and based on that update its inner matrix transition probability.

Any help and guidelines in this regard are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You can define a `struct` (or even a `class`) to represent each element of the big matrix, then use an array (or `std::vector`) of such structures. I'm assuming you know about structures.

Comment: Are the dimensions, 3x3 inner and 4x4 outer, constant within your problem area ? Have you decided whether you would rather learn about an existing library, or write the linear algebra code you might need by all by yourself on an ongoing basis ?

Comment: @AdrianMole, thanks a lot. Is it a good practice to define structs inside a class? as follows: class MatrixElement{
public:
 typedef struct
 {
   double m_timeIntervalProbability [3][3];
   uint16_t m_timeIntervalCounter[3][3];
   uint16_t m_totalTimeIntervals[3];
 } TimeIntervalMatrix;
 //We'll use TimeIntervalMatrix type as a type of a member of the following struct.
 typedef struct
 {
     double m_locationProbability [5][5];
     uint16_t m_locationCounter [5][5];
     uint16_t m_totalNumOfVisits [5];
     TimeIntervalMatrix m_timeIntervalMatrix;
 } LocationMatrix;
 
};

Comment: @jpmarinier, yes the matrices are static, the image contains 4x4 matrix, however I am actually using 5x5 matrix, and a 3x3 inner matrix. The size of the matrices will remain constant